# Change color on mdl-textfield

Tags: html, css, material-design, textfield, material-design-lite

Is there a built in way to change the color of a Material Design Lite [text field](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section)? In particular, the default text and underline before the text field is used. In the below example the "Text..." and underline are gray by default. I need them to be white as I'm using a dark background.

```
<!-- Simple Textfield -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I don't want to change the color of the text or underline after the text field is selected, just the text and underline when the text field is unused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just override the default stylesheet:

```
.mdl-textfield__input{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.mdl-textfield__label{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked:

```
.mdl-textfield__label:after {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some code in the css library file, it look like this:

```
.mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label,.mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-dirty .mdl-textfield__label,.mdl-textfield--floating-label.has-placeholder .mdl-textfield__label{color:#3f51b5;font-size:12px;top:4px;visibility:visible}
```

then I tried to override my style in website, just change the "**color**", it work!
there's more info at the css files.
***B)***